# Change computer name for shared folders?

Tags: azure, windows-server-2012

I want to share folders to people from Windows server 2012 so they can save files.

How can I change the UNC path for the server? Is there anyway to make the name a bit cleaner. I do not want to actually change the server name, just the display path (similar to a domain name for hosting a website).

//AzeAppLongNameVeryUgly27/test_folder

To:

//new_name/test_folder

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would find out how the name resolution works in a Windows network. (Search words WINS, DNS) Then you will also understand how to use it.

Typically, a DNS server will be commissioned to provide so-called "friendly names". (DNS [CNAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) Records). In DNS Manager, expand  > Forward Lookup Zones

Alternatively, a [computer name aliases](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2017/06/19/using-computer-name-aliases-in-place-of-dns-cname-records/) can be used.